# Is the ThanksKilling franchise the only franchise to skip its sequel?

Tags: sequels, thankskilling

After being funded by Kickstarter, ThanksKilling 3 came out in 2012. At the time, [it was marketed as the first movie to skip its sequel](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2106675/trivia?item=tr1861286). This means that the first and third movies were made, but not the second one (a few clips are shown in the movie, but the second movie is largely just a plot element for the third).

In this case, ThanksKilling is a movie that references a possible sequel. ThanksKilling 3 is a movie that references Thanksilling 2. ThanksKilling 2 is not a movie. Thanksgiving 2 was [teased](http://www.horror-movies.ca/2012/04/thankskilling-2-will-be-set-in-space/) before the release of ThanksKilling 3 and up until the release of the third movie, it looked like the second movie would actually be released.

Searching Google about skipped sequels and prequels has largely led me to sequels that should have never been made or Star Wars, so I am wondering whether or not ThanksKilling the first franchise to skip a sequel entirely. Has a franchise done it since?

Comment: Have you read this article: http://www.denofgeek.com/movies/ignored/34325/10-sequels-that-ignored-previous-films, I dind't understand the situation you are not looking for. If this article helps you I can add it as an answer =)

Comment: @GustavoGabriel Asker is after the franchise where one of the sequel is missing, like there was no ThanksKilling 2.

Comment: @GustavoGabriel I saw it before, but didn't read it (I did glance at it now though). That seems to be more talking about retconning the story to exclude certain prequels, opposed to the sequels simply not existing.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Thanks. If you have a suggestion for how to make the wording clearer, let me know or edit. I've been thinking circles in my head about this for a couple hours and I think that is starting to show up in my writing.

Comment: Oh, I get it, in that case I don't think there is any movie that did that. Googled a lot and didn't find any anyways. =(

Comment: I was always under the impression that a sequel referred to its prior production of that name, and not to a book series or to a subject script that was deemed as not worthy of production. I think a lot of people will simply say a sequel is the next movie, period.

Comment: Horror franchises are prone to such inconsistencies. The *House* films are really *House I*, *II* & *IV*, with *House III* [not considered a real sequel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_IV). *The Eye 2* was followed by *The Eye 10*, but it's just a name.

Comment: @Walt I'm thinking less inconsistencies and more they intentionally skipped a sequel - they did everything but make and release the movie. I'll look into the House films though. A quick glance is kinda promising because House III wasn't even called that when it was released.

Answer (score 8):

[Naked Gun 33 1/3](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110622/) is in fact only the third film in the series.

Comment: True and made me laugh... +33.3333 points

Comment: Wasn't Naked Gun 2 1/2 only just the second film in the series? ;)

Comment: Not quite the same, but there is The Lion King 1 1/2 and is a meta film that's a sequel (thye watch the first film in the theater) and a prequel (Timon tells his backstory),  before the Lion King 2!

Answer (score 3):

Who can forget [Leonard pt 6. (1987)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093405/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)? The only entry in it's franchise (thank goodness) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The obvious example that comes to mind is the [rebranding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_(film)#Title) of *Star Wars* as *Star Wars: Episode IV*.

Of course, episodes I, II and III would be made, but not for over two decades.